# Swift Scale custom view to fit inside its view

Tags: swift, swift5, custom-view

G´day,

I am playing around with custom views. I got stuck now at a point where I have created a custom view that is quite big and I want it to be scaled inside the view that I assign it to. The custom view appears in the correct uiview but it's not scaled.

This is the code for the custom view.

```
class Brakes: UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var copilot_pedals_imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var pilot_pedals_imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var left_slave_valve_imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var right_slave_valve_imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var parking_brake_valve_imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var left_brake_imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var right_brake_imageView: UIImageView!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupview()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        setupview()
    }

    func setupview() {
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("Brakes", owner: self, options: nil)
        addSubview(containerView)
        containerView.frame = self.bounds
        containerView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    }

}
```

In the ViewController

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var handleView: PBHandle!
    @IBOutlet weak var advisoriesView: Advisories!
    @IBOutlet weak var brake: Brakes!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        brake.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }
}
```

In the ViewController I have tried to do brake.sizeToFit() and brake.layoutSubviews() without any success.

Any suggestions?

Jonas

Comment: Assuming `brake` is a view in the storyboard, you need to make constraints. If not, just set `brake.frame`.

Comment: That is correct, brake is a view in the storyboard. It has constraints, horizontal to center of the viewcontroller, to the bottom of safe area, size (both height and width).

Comment: Instead of height and width, just do left, right, top, bottom to safe area (or superview, safe area just ignores the notch, status bar, and the home indicator)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that did not work either.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your storyboard? If you want, I can take a look at your project file

Comment: https://github.com/Jonasraf/Test

Comment: Thanks! Going to sleep right now. I’ll get back to you in the morning.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223828/discussion-between-aheze-and-jonas-rafnsson).